# Vue3 app on vite can't compile scss syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vite

I can't use `scss` nesting syntax.

**`_table.scss`**

`table {   &.table {     width: 100%;   } }`
[results in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5V7r.png)

I imported my `_table.scss` file into `main.scss` and `main.scss` into `main.js`
[main.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkrjp.png)
[main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMoER.png)

**Here is my package.json dependencies**

```json
{
  "name": "morphzing-vue3",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lintfix": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src --ignore-path .gitignore . --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.7.0",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.23",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/js": "^7.0.96",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "vite": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

**And my vite.config.js**

```js
    import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
    
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
    
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [vue()],
      server: {
        port: 8080,
        hot: true
      },
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
      },
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            additionalData: `
              @import "./src/assets/variables.scss";
              @import "./src/assets/theme/colors.scss";
            `
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

I followed the [vite API](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-pre-processors)

If I use simple syntax .block .block__item or use scss syntax in vue components - it works fine:

**Simple syntax in my _table.scss file**

```css
    table td {
      vertical-align: middle;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

[image: results in dev tools]

**vue components**

```html
    <style lang="scss" module>
        .block:global(.v-navigation-drawer--is-hovering) {
          .block__logo {
            padding: 24px;
          }
          .block__nav--nested {
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 12px;
          }
        }
        .block:not(:global(.v-navigation-drawer--is-hovering)) {
          .block__nav {
            padding: 0;
        
            &--nested {
              padding: 0;
              padding-left: 4px;
            }
          }
        }
    </style>
```

[image: results in dev tools]

Also I tried use sass-loader, It's not working in my case(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleagues found a solution. We had to remove import through url in `main.scss`

Now my code in main.scss looks like this

```css
@import './parts/_table.scss';

@import './typography.scss';
@import './helpers.scss';

@import './variables.scss';
@import './theme/colors.scss';
```

And nesting syntax from scss is working